# Changes to copied Audio object in child component mutates original

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The component receives an object of audios objects. I pass one of these to a child component and update the `.onended` attribute. This also mutates the audio object within the original object that was passed to the parent! I then make a copy of the audios object to and pass that instead, but same problem.

Apologies for the contrived code:

```
const Child = ({audio, forceReload}) => {
  audio.onended = () => {console.log("has on ended")}
  useEffect(() => {
    // updates state of parent
    forceReload(true)
  }, [])
  return null
}

const Parent = ({audios}) => {

  const [_, forceReload] = useState(false)
  const audiosCOPY = {...audios}
  console.log(audios["cloud"].onended)


 return <Child audio={audiosCOPY["cloud"]} forceReload={forceReload} />
}
```

Output:

First render log:

```
 null
```

Second:

```
ƒ () {
    console.log("has on ended");
  }
```

Comment: You are spreading the same `cloud` attribute from the original object over the new object.  You need to create a new `cloud` object and pass that to your `Child` component.

Comment: The root of the issue here is that `{...audios}` creates a _shallow_ copy, not a deep copy, of the `audios` object. You can either find a way to deep-copy the object or just copy down to the level you need.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the `audios.cloud` attribute.  You would likely need to create a copy of that attribute instead of creating a copy of the audios object.  Something like this might work:

```
<Child audio={{...audiosCOPY['cloud']}} ... />
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I was sure this would work when  read it but it a copy of that object. Is an empty object. From '<audio preload="auto" src="http://localhost:5000/public/cold.mp3"></audio>'

Comment: That being the case, you might want to investigate Nick's comment to your question; creating a deep copy of your object.  Lodash has this built-in, or there are a number of ways of creating a deep copy.  If that doesn't work, you're going to need to show some code so we can better understand what you are trying to do.  https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep